# Why do I keep blowing my PSU?

Tags: power-management

Yesterday I blew two PSU's on my machine.  It's a Corsair box, and the first PSU was high spec (Antec 750W Gamer).  The second was just a bog standard PSU.

Both blew in the same power point. I have a multi-meter stuck in it at the moment and have some suspicious readings.  (I got over 700 volts for about 30 seconds yesterday.  My meter is pretty old though, so I'm not 100% confident of the reading).

So, I have a few questions:

1. Is there any possibility at all that my box/motherboard/machine could be causing the issue?
2. Is there any way I can use Linux to monitor the input voltages?  (I read a bit about lm-sensors but that just measures the output of the PSU.  That could be handy, but what I really need is the input to the PSU.)
3. What kind of protection should I be looking at?  I haven't been a fan of this in the past because it seemed a minefield - you could end up spending a reasonable amount of money and still end up with something that was inadequate.

Thanks!

Comment: This is crazy...can you provide details about the rest of the configuration of the system?  (I'm assuming by 'blew' you mean 'the power supplies are now completely nonfunctional')

Comment: Does 'in the 'same power point' mean the same wall outlet. One which fluctates up to 700 volt? In that case do not plug anything into it. First check the multimeter or try another one, then fix the problem at the (power) source.

Comment: OK, so I have lodged a call with the electricity provider and am now running through a surge protector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uhm, this may seem like a dumb question, but are you using a surge protector? If not, that's the reason....

Aside from that, I would **seriously** get my house wiring looked at if you're getting 700 volts on a 120v or 240v line.

Comment: Seconded...  700V for 30 seconds? Call an electrician now.

Comment: Most high quality power supplies die because of bad external power or poor ventilation. Any gaming power supply will limit the amount of power draw that the components can consume. If you have a bad device that is trying to pull a massive load, the power supply will limit the power supplied to protect itself.

Comment: 240 volts AC is only supposed to go up  sqrt(2) * 240  volt. That is half of what you measured.  (sanity check, you did select AC mode? )

Comment: Somehow I missed the **700 volts** when I originally read that...that's not right.